# Installer fails when launched using Process.Start() but works when double-clicked

Tags: c#, windows-xp

I'm having issues with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`.

When I am launching a third-party installer (MSI package wrapped in an executable), it installs without problems when it is launched by double-clicking the exe or invoked from the command line.

However, when I'm launching it from within an application by using `Process.Start()`, the installer fails with error code 5 = access denied. The logs say that it fails because it cannot restore some Registry settings.

Does anyone know the difference (security-wise) between double-clicking the exe and launching a process from within the application? User runs as administrator.

Example code:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = @"C:\MyFolder\setup.exe";
info.UseShellExecute = false; // I have tried both true and false here

Process p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();

if (p.ExitCode != 0)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I put the code above in a small console application and it worked. Obviously something fishy was going on in the main app...

It turned out I had forgotten to close some Registry keys. The installer failed since it tried to access those same keys. As soon as I closed the keys properly, the code worked.

Sorry folks. Shame on me.

Comment: @Kipotlov - the question is tagged windows-xp.

Comment: You may have to pass command line arguments down into the MSI through the installer if the normal execution requires user interaction to allow certain actions. An example of how you're setting up this Process object and calling it might help.

Comment: @Chris did you solve the problem? I am facing a similar issue to this.

Answer (score 0):

So that might not work the way you'd expect it to anyway; I'm assuming you're going for an unattended installation. Try something like this:

```
Process installer = new Process()
installer.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\MyFolder\Setup.exe";
installer.StartInfo.Arguments = " /s /v\" /qn\"";
installer.Start()
installer.WaitForExit();

if ( installer.ExitCode != 0 )
{
   //do something
}
```

The argument tells the installer exe to run silently ( /s ) and to pass arguments down to the MSI ( /v ). The /qn is the Windows Installer argument to run the installer silently, which should require no user interaction and should allow the installer to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting info.Verb = "runas"?

This will make the application/installer run as administrator.  It is the same thing as right clicking an icon and telling it to run as administrator